# Getting incorrect subimage from java

Tags: java, sprite, bufferedimage

In my game I am trying to make an animated walking sequence, so I'm trying to make sure that the image will changedepending on which animation frame it is on. When the space bar is pressed the image changes, but instead of getting the next image from my spritesheet I get the next image and the previous image. I have screenshots of the problem below, as well as the code.

---

Before space is pressed

[image: before]

After Space Is Pressed

[image: after]

---

Code

```
private static BufferedImage image;
private static BufferedImage[] cropped = new BufferedImage[15]; 
private static byte frame = 0;

public Player(){
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("DownWalking.png"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void drawPlayer(int x,int y,Graphics2D g2){
    if (frame == 0){
        cropped[0] = image.getSubimage(2, 1, 23, 43);   
    }
    if (frame == 1){
        cropped[1] = image.getSubimage(34, 1, 54, 45);
    }

g2.drawImage(cropped[frame],x * Tile.tileSize, y * Tile.tileSize, cropped[frame].getWidth(), cropped[frame].getHeight(), null);
```

Comment: Method signature is getSubimage(x, y, w, h) it looks like you might have (x1,y1,x2,y2) on accident? image.getSubimage(34, 1, 54, 45); -> image.getSubimage(34, 1, 23, 43); unless your 2nd frame is more than 2x as wide as your first

Comment: Thank you so much! I did think it was cropping from point A to point B, and your explanation helped a lot! @ns47731

Comment: @ns47731: I think you are spot on. Please edit and post as an answer, so we can have the question marked as answered. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature for `getSubImage` is:

```
getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h)
```

You had`getSubimage(x1,y1,x2,y2)` causing your image to get 2 tiles instead of 1.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)